# How to avoid returning undefined if condition is not met

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am building a react app and I have an array of objects (items) that I would like to loop over and display the various objects based on an index. I set the index using useState and a button that the user clicks.

```
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    const itemsLength = items.length;

    const nextBtn = () => {
    if(index <= itemsLength) {
        setIndex(index + 1);
    } else {
        setIndex(0)
    }
   }
```

When I console.log the index it starts at 0 and gets to 3 just fine, but after reaching the itemsLength where it should setIndex to 0, it returns undefined and I have to click on the button 3 times before it gets back to 0.

How can I get it to get back to 0 without returning undefined.

I am new to javascript and have been at this for hours. Please help.

Comment: `if (index >= length) set(0); else set(index + 1);`

Comment: Remember that in "array", "index" starts at 0 but "length" starts at 1, and when the index reaches the last element of the array, the length is actually index + 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function must be like this:

```
const nextBtn = () => {
    if (index < itemsLength - 1) {
      setIndex(index + 1);
    } else {
      setIndex(0);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Its not me who voted negative mate on your comment, but i was checking on why he commented negative i think by adding just `<` you've already counted  array length minus 1,

Comment: If you wanted to say  `if (index < itemsLength - 1)` you should've put  `if (index <= itemsLength - 1)`

Comment: This actually worked for me, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Its because array is zero indexed, and you're counting from zero
it means ten elements is from 0 to 9 and not 10 exactly so be careful on using `<=` and check if just `<` will work for you.

Look below example where mine loops just fine

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 19];

  const nextBtn = () => {
    setIndex((prev) => {
      if (prev < items.length) {
        return prev + 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={nextBtn}>
        next {index}
      </button>
    </div>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: your items have 10 lengths but the index state reaches from 0 to 10 and this means index has 11 numbers. so items[index] is undefined where the index is 10 . and I don't understand WHY you voted me a negative!!!

Comment: FYI [snippets support React code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: please run `console.log(items[index])` on your code and you see when index is 10 `items[index]` is undefined.

Comment: For some reason, this works all the way to the last one, then it returns undefined.

Comment: Then i think, its a problem with index, as @Mohsen007 said, and i think its right thing to add - 1 to the length as he did